# AutoFit on rows that are referenced from different sheet using function - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I would like to make an autofit to the referenced cells from another sheet, so everytime when I add some infos on one sheet my row height expands, the code below makes that possible:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Target.WrapText = True
Target.EntireRow.AutoFit

End Sub
```

But as I say this is possible only if I manually typing something anywhere in my workbook, but what about when I have on another sheet (same workbook) some functions that are referencing those values? the fields are not expanding even though it is a right match...

For instance I am having this infos in one sheet (wrapped) as one value:

```
Column A
AAABBBCCCDDD
EEEFFFGGGHHH
```

and when using this function on another sheet to make them referenced:

```
=IFNA(IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(INDEX(Table1[Systembezeichnung];MATCH(Ausdruck!$A$5;Table1[Nummer];0)):INDEX(Table1[Systembezeichnung];MATCH(Ausdruck!$A$5;Table1[Nummer];0)+9);ROW(4:4)));"";INDEX(INDEX(Table1[Systembezeichnung];MATCH(Ausdruck!$A$5;Table1[Nummer];0)):INDEX(Table1[Systembezeichnung];MATCH(Ausdruck!$A$5;Table1[Nummer];0)+9);ROW(4:4)));"")
```

it gives me everything in one row but not expanding or wrapped as I want:

```
Column A
AAABBBCCCDDDEEEFFFGGGHHH
```

It has to be automatically wrapped for the sake of dynamic document that I am providing, without loss of infos or that some infos are missing or "hidden".

Comment: You may try to write codes to `Workbook_SheetCalculate` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Workbook_SheetCalculate` event. A simple example will be like below.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("D2:D5").WrapText = True
        .Range("D2:D5").EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

So, if you have any formula to range `D2:D5` on sheet2 and when you will change any value to any sheet of workbook and if it changes any value to `D2:D5` then that cell row will automatically fit.

> Edit: For full sheet you can try below codes.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Cells.WrapText = True
    .Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
End With
```

[Microsoft reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetcalculate)

Comment: good point, but what if I have many formula ranges on the sheet that have to be updated?

Comment: You can then run code for full sheet cells. See my edits.