# Auto fit row height on other worksheets from a activex combobox

Tags: excel, vba

Firstly I cannot program in VBA but I know how useful it is. Secondly my Excel version is 2010 but the organisation has 365.

I have a project that is to be used to help a voluntary organisation in the UK comply with a new food labelling law. I have one in use but all line heights have to be adjusted manually with the risk that if not done some ingredients will not be stated.

The main sheet called View, it is for selecting a meal option in an activeX combobox drop down and via VLOOKUP's displaying a list of ingredients from the Data sheet. On the View sheet are also the buttons to run a number of print macros. Because of the very variable contents of each cell I need to reset row height after each selection, which I do on the View sheet as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Sheets("View").Select
Range("B3:B19").Select
Selection.Rows.AutoFit
End Sub
```

What I also need to do is reset row height on set ranges on other linked sheets as well. Linked to the View sheet are other sheets called Ingredients (which specifies what ingredients have to be used), Notice (headed A4 notice of all ingredients used) and Labels (same information as Notice but 6 to a page for takeaway food labels) which can be printed from the macro buttons. I have googled and found a number of suggested solutions, including this one:

[AutoFit on rows that are referenced from different sheet using function - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733829/autofit-on-rows-that-are-referenced-from-different-sheet-using-function-vba)

but for whatever reason I could not get any to work. Is there a way that I can get selected ranges of rows on the other sheets to work off of the Combobox change on the View sheet, either by modifying the above code or putting Private Subs into the other sheets? I have already tried using variations of the View code without success.

Comment: You don't have to select a sheet or a range to change it, just use `Sheets("View").Rows("3:19").AutoFit`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. This is what I now have: 'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'To reset row heights on all printable sheets on selection in Combobox
    Sheets("View").Rows("3:19").AutoFit
    Sheets("Ingredients").Rows("5:22").AutoFit
    Sheets("Notice").Rows("5:19").AutoFit
    Sheets("Labels").Rows("1:39").AutoFit
    
End Sub'

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked thanks to CDP1802

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'To reset row heights on all printable sheets on selection in Combobox
Sheets("View").Rows("3:19").AutoFit
Sheets("Ingredients").Rows("5:22").AutoFit
Sheets("Notice").Rows("5:19").AutoFit
Sheets("Labels").Rows("1:39").AutoFit

End Sub
```